# Filter lines that contains exact match of a string

Tags: python

I am trying to filter the lines in a file that contains exact match of a string, in python. 
To begin with, I've written the following section of the code,

```
lines = ["z  = xxx;  %eflee","x  = eee ;  %flee"]

for lineNo,line in enumerate(lines):
    tags = ["flee"]
    for tag in tags:
        if tag in line:
           print(line)
```

Desired Output:

```
x  = eee ;  %flee
```

Obtained output:

```
z  = xxx;  %eflee
x  = eee ;  %flee
```

Could someone explain how to get the desired output?

Comment: %eflee also contains flee, why not add % to tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to match each of your tags as a whole word only:

```
import re

lines = ["z  = xxx;  %eflee","x  = eee ;  %flee"]

for lineNo,line in enumerate(lines):
    tags = ["flee"]
    for tag in tags:
        if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % tag, line):
           print(line)
```

Output:

```
x  = eee ;  %flee
```

r'\bflee\b' is a regular expression that matches only the whole word 'flee'.  It works because '\b' means to only match at a word boundary.

If it's possible that you could match two tags in a single line, and you don't want to then print the same line twice, you should put "break" under "print(line)" at the same indentation level.

You don't use lineNo.  If you really don't need it, you can change your 'for' line to:

```
for line in lines:
```

Comment: This helps in achieving my goal. I'm still curious to know if there are ways of matching the exact string and not print the lines that contain substring.i.e flee and not eflee.I've edited my question to avoid any confusion.Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure there are.  Regular expressions are great at doing this.  So you want to know how to just match whole words, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know how to match the whole word

Comment: Have you experienced regular expressions before?  If not, then they can be a little strange.  But they let you do amazing things.  I've come up with a few answers on SO, by providing a pretty simple regular expression, that seemed like pure magic to the person asking the question .  I'd wholeheartedly suggest learning about them.

Comment: I'll definitely spend time in learning more about how regular expressions work.This is actually awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re


lines = ["z  = xxx;  %eflee","x  = eee ;  %flee"]
tags = ["flee"]
pattern = "|".join([" %{} ?".format(t) for t in tags])
# pattern: ' %flee ?'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for lineNo,line in enumerate(lines):
    if regex.search(line):
        print(line)
```